# Multiply and sum each row by other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I would like to Multiply and sum each row by other rows, i.e.
Input

```
Name Value
A     0.3
B     0.5
C     0.2
D     0.1
```

Output

```
Name Value
A     0.3*0.5+ 0.3*0.2*+ 0.3*0.1
B     0.5*0.3 +0.5*0.2 + 0.5*0.1
C     0.2*0.3 +0.2*0.5 + 0.2*0.1
D     0.1*0.3 +0.1*0.5 + 0.1*0.2
```

I have 34 rows so manually inputting will not do.
Thank you very much

Comment: `,` ... is not a decimal point.

Comment: What did you code to compute your solution? What problem arose? Where is the [mre]?

Comment: You're allowed to change your selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation for your solution will be

**(Summation of all values except the current one)*(current value)**

Use `apply lambda` with `axis=1`.
`x.name` will give you the current index for each row. Simple make slices for each row with excluding the current value. Get a sum of slice and multiply it by current value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["A","B","C","D"],"Value":[0.3,0.5,0.2,0.1]})
df["new_value"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[df.index != x.name ,"Value"].sum()*x["Value"] ,axis=1)
print(df)


   Name Value   new_value
0   A   0.3       0.24
1   B   0.5       0.30
2   C   0.2       0.18
3   D   0.1       0.10
```

Comment: My way is much simpler and yields identical results: https://ideone.com/coupnj

Answer (score 4):

If you factor it out the `Value` for the current row from your expression, you should be able to see that for each row, you're trying to compute `Value * (X - Value)`, where `X` is the sum of the `Value` column.

So the result is

```
df['Value'] * (df['Value'].sum() - df['Value'])
```

No need for complicated per-element operations at all.